# drop function returning KeyError | Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm studying for a Data Science Olympiad competition and i have ran into a little problem. All ive done is converted values in a row with values ranging 2-8 into good or bad using a bin, then i used the label encoder to make them 1 or 0

when running this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, LabelEncoder

#load our data file
data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", delimiter=";")

#classify wines as good or bad
bins = (1,5,8)
group_names = ['bad', "good"]
data["quality"] = pd.cut(data["quality"], bins=bins, labels=group_names)
print(data["quality"].unique())

#list the labels as good or bad to 1 or 0
label_quality = LabelEncoder()
data["quality"] = label_quality.fit_transform(data["quality"])

#create our feature ad result sets
X = data.drop(data["quality"], axis=1)
y = data["quality"]

#create our training sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=10)

print(data.head(100))
```

i run into the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>    X = data.drop(data["quality"], axis=1)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3990, in drop    return super().drop(
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3936, in drop    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3970, in _drop_axis    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/home/runner/.local/share/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5018, in drop    raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis")
KeyError: '[0 0 0 ... 1 0 1] not found in axis'
```

it says my row values aren't found in the axis but i already specified axis one so shouldn't it cut it?

Comment: Check the syntax for `drop()` again. It takes the name of a column, not the full series (`'quality'` not `data['quality']`)

Comment: For the drop command, try `X = data.drop(['quality'], axis=1)` or `X = data.drop(columns=['quality'], axis=1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a mistake in you python code , drop function takes columns names as a list not the column itself just try below code it should work fine

```
#create our feature ad result sets
y = data["quality"]
X = data.drop(["quality"], axis=1)
```

and one more thing before dropping you have to copy that column in y otherwise it will give error as column 'quality' has been dropped